# Why is the Lexicon Receptacle missing?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am level 24. Got the Blank Lexicon and Attunement Sphere from Septimus. Both of these items are in my inventory, so clearly I can't drop them.

For whatever reason, the actual pedestal that you're supposed to place the Blank Lexicon in isn't there... I obviously haven't gotten the Elder Scroll yet, because I need to use the Lexicon to do so (but again, I can't because the freaking pedestal isn't physically there...). I have both Elder Knowledge and Discerning the Transmundane in my quests.

Have no idea what the problem is.. On top of that, my last Save (not quick save) is from when I was like level 5, so if I load I have a hell of a lot to make up. I always quick save because I'm an idiot I guess.

I play on PS4 and use mods, but nothing I use should affect the game this tremendously.

[image]

Comment: I forgot, does Skyrim have multiple autosaves? If so, does the furthest one back predate when you started the quest?

Comment: No, sadly you can only use Saves to load, not Autosaves :-/

Comment: Ah, it's been quite a while since my Skyrim phase... I was thinking of the way Fallout 4 handled autosaves.

Comment: @Vemonus no worries at all :-)

Comment: It was a mod that messed it up! I was wrong hahaha. I had the "Wearable Elder Scroll" enabled when I thought it wasn't. Thanks for the help you two :-)

Answer (score 5):

I had the "Wearable Elder Scroll" enabled when I thought it wasn't.  Make sure you don't have this mod on if you do the quest or intend to. As of right now, there's no solution if you had it enabled, even after you disabled it :-/

Answer (score 0):

On the top of that structure there are a few button stands. Most will be closed, with one open. You need to click that open button until you get another button. The buttons adjust the lenses (the ones on top of the sphere). You have to solve a puzzle with the buttons to align the lenses, and once you manage to do so, you can set the lexicon. The lexicon receptable is "inside" the pedestal you showed in your image.

Comment: None of the buttons are open?? :-/

Comment: It was a mod that messed it up! I was wrong hahaha. I had the "Wearable Elder Scroll" enabled when I thought it wasn't. Thanks for the help you two :-)

Comment: Well, I assumed it was Vanilla =)

Comment: It's all good :-)